# making hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an arraylist (eg: h1) contain some urls.
eg: http://www.google.com,http://www.yahoo.com,http://www.xyz.com,.....

How can i put hyperlinks to each elements in that arraylist in c# ? Means by clicking on that url it should navigate to corresponding website.Can you give an example??

Also, how can i use 'Hyperlink' keyword in c# ?

Comment: Maybe you could accept some answers to your previous questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>` object to your ASP.NET page, and add this to your page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(object link in myArrayList)
    {
        string url = link as string;
        if(url != null)
        {
            HyperLink l = new HyperLink();
            l.NavigateUrl = l.Text = url;
            myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var links = h1.Cast<string>().Select(l => new HyperLink() { NavigateUrl = l, Text = l })

foreach (var link in links)
{
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(link);
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>");
}
```

This will add all links from an `ArrayList` as strings to a panel called `Panel1` (which can be substituted for any other [`ContainerControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx#familyToggle)).

Comment: As long as you have a .NET 3.5 application, and in that case there is no need to have an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Definitely, but the question specifically says an `ArrayList`, so I'm keeping it to the point.

Comment: Yes, but most likely this is some ancient .NET 1.1 app.

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway. Doesn't look like anyone will get their answer accepted going by this user's statistics.

Comment: why, any other thing instead of arraylist in .NET 3.5??

Comment: In .NET 3.5 you can use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList` which will give you a typed-collection. They're far easier to use since you don't have to cast to string whenever you retrieve an item.